# change centre of google map with change in city name from action method in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

**I have a simple java script code like this---**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var localityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchLocalities")';
        var subLocalityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchSubLocalities")';
        var localities = $('#SelectedLocality');
        var subLocalities = $('#SelectedSubLocality');
        $('#SelectedCity').change(function () {
            codeAddress();
            localities.empty();
            subLocalities.empty();
            $.getJSON(localityUrl, { ID: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                if (!data) {
                   // codeAddress();
                    return;
                }
                localities.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    localities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                });
            });
        })
```

**and my codeAddress function is something like this--**

```
   function codeAddress() {
                var lat = document.getElementById('SelectedCity').Latitude;
                var lng = document.getElementById('SelectedCity').Longitude;
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

**and my FetchCities action method is---**

```
      public List<City> FetchCities()
   {
       List<City> cities = new List<City>();
       cities.Add(new City() { Id = 1 , Name = "--Select Your City--" });
       cities.Add(new City() { Id = 2, Name = "Faridabaad", Latitude = 28.4211M, Longitude = 77.3078M });
       cities.Add(new City() { Id = 3, Name = "Greater Noida", Latitude = 28.4962M, Longitude = 77.5360M });
       return cities;
      }
```

I want to change google map with change in city name by calling the codeAddress function. My problem is that initially google map is loading fine but there is no change in google map with city name changing.You can have a look at full code here http://pastebin.com/6HWcPg9a and my controller is--http://pastebin.com/2zy7fNTj
Plzz tell me is my codeAddress function is correct or not???will it work inside SelectedCity.change(function).What changes to be made if any plzz help me**

**Right now, i have tried geocoding feature of google map and tried to pass latitude longitude but failed once again---the code is like this it's not working it's showing some other places on google map--**

```
  var address = document.getElementById('SelectedCity').value;
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        var myOptions = {
                            zoom: 13,
                            center: latlng,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see there are few errors:

1. There are no methods nor properties like Latitude and Longitude.
2. You're not populating  element with none of this data.

Replace this line:

```js
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    localities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                });
```

with that:

```js
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        localities.append($('<option data-lat='+item.Latitude +' data-lng='+item.Longitude+'></option>').text(item.Text));
                    });
```

and this:

```js
var lat = document.getElementById('SelectedCity').Latitude;
                    var lng = document.getElementById('SelectedCity').Longitude;
```

with that:

```js
var lat = $('#SelectedCity').data('lat'),
                    lng = $('#SelectedCity').data('lng');
```

And one more thing. There is a nice field in MSSQL called dbgeography for storing coordinates with few nice extra properties. Google it ;-)

Comment: I tried it but it's not working....only canvas is showing just like before with change in city name but no google map showing @Tomasz

Comment: @AshishSrivastava do you have this app somewhere public so I can look at it? If not try to console.log values of lat and lng to check if they exist.

Comment: the changes to be made u have provided in second one var lat = $('#SelectedCity').data('lat'), here there is a comma instead of semi colon what should i use ?? if i use comma then it start showing errors

Comment: oh sorry... either remove second var or replace comma with semicolon